# How to change “Dashboard” text in wordpress

Tags: customization

[image]

I need to change "Dashboard" text in wordpress admin section. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the code below on your functions you should be able to filter the `global $title` easily on the `admin_head` action.

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_head', 'q167372_dash_name' );
function q167372_dash_name(  ){
    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'index.php' ){
        return;
    }

    $GLOBALS['title'] =  __( 'Your new Title' ); 
}
```

Comment: `if` check is wrong in your code. `dashboard` should be `index.php`

Comment: I've updated your code and it's working. Thanks mate!